# Unable to deserialize HttpResponseMessage to an object

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclientfactory

I am working on `IHttpClientFactory` in .net core 6 application to read httpClient data and object is to deserialize into object `APIResponse`

`error`

```
cannot convert string to System.IO.Stream
```

I have tried also ReadAsStreamAsync in which case get empty object.

`Calling below method`

```
var dd = _httpClientServices.GetRequestAsync<APIResponse>(httpClientConfig, null);
```

`var response = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();`

```
 public class HttpClientServices : IHttpClientService
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public HttpClientServices(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        this._httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public async Task<TResponse> GetRequestAsync<TResponse>(HttpClientConfig httpClientConfig, string token) where TResponse : class
    {
        try
        {
            var apiUri = QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(httpClientConfig.ClientAPIUrl, httpClientConfig.Parameters);

            HttpClient httpClient = CreateClient(httpClientConfig, null);

            HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, apiUri);

            HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);

            if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var response = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response))
                {
                    var responseData = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<TResponse>(response); //getting error here..............
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

`API Response Object`

```
 public class APIResponse
{
    public APIResponseStatus APIResponseStatus { get; set; }
    public int RecordCount { get; set; }
    public dynamic? ResponseData { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[DeserializeAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserializeasync?view=net-6.0) only accepts a `Stream` parameter, but `response` response is a `string`. There's no IO involved when deserializing an in-memory string, so a `DeserializeAsync` for strings wouldn't be useful.

The first solution would be to use `Deserialize` :

```
var responseData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TResponse>(response);
```

The second would be to read the response as a stream and deserialize asynchronously. This preserves memory for large responses because it doesn't have to allocate a string to contain the entire response before deserialization

```
var stream = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
var responseData = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<TResponse>(stream);
```

Comment: with stream I am getting empty object

Comment: My client certainly does send object with data but after deserialzation, I get empty object

Answer (score 1):

```
var apiResponse = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<APIResponse>();
```